Gcloud builds submit error
I am having a script folder with a python script, docker file and also a requirements.txt
My python script is running individually well, locally.
Python script
import os
import time
from fastapi import FastAPI
import uvicorn

app = FastAPI()


SHARED_VOLUME_PATH = '/mnt/shared'
@app.get("/")
def process_data():
    data = "From Primary car"
    
    with open(os.path.join(SHARED_VOLUME_PATH, 'shared_data_file.txt'), 'w') as f:
        f.write(data)
    
    print("Data processed and stored in shared volume")
    response = "Data processed and stored in shared volume"
    return response

if __name__ == '__main__':
    port = int(os.environ.get("PORT", 8080))
    uvicorn.run(app, host="0.0.0.0", port=port)
    process_data()


Docker file content is the following
FROM python:3.11

WORKDIR /app

COPY requirements.txt .
RUN pip install --no-cache-dir -r requirements.txt

COPY main.py .

CMD ["python", "main.py"]

When I run the command
gcloud builds submit --tag europe-west4-docker.pkg.dev/<GCP-project-ID>/artifactory/scar-prim-component:latest

I am getting this error.
ERROR: (gcloud.builds.submit) HTTPError 412: 'us' violates constraint 'constraints/gcp.resourceLocations'

I am not very strong in this area. Please advise what I need to change so that i can push my code as an artifactory component in GCP.
I ran the same script and performed the same steps in a different GCP project and it worked fine and got deployed as well.
If there is an alternate means to build and push to the artifactory, please advise the steps (in detail)

You should use region supported by Google Cloud Builds.
It can be specified in default profile configuration or by setting worker pool.
Please feel free to ask comments or another questions!

I used docker build and then pushed that image into the GCP antifactory. It got pushed without any problem. only if I use gcloud builds submit, then it gives this problem
